# How to properly handle the angular route subscription and then use the parameters for parallel http requests

Tags: angular, rxjs

I try to get the proper solution for the following scenario:

I got an Observable from the subscription to the route parameters. Now if this subscription fires it should start two parallel http requests.

I tried to combine switchMap with forkJoin. Sadly this didn't work. The following code works, but I think I shouldn't use a subscription in a subscription? So what's the proper solution?

```
this.subscriptions.add(this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
   this.subscriptions.add(forkJoin(
     [this.componentService.getComponentDetails( params.id ), this.planService.getPlanTypes()]
   ).subscribe(
     (data) => {
       console.log(data);
     },
     (error) => {
       console.error('Error loading Form: ', error);
     }
   ));
}));
```

The subscriptions object is afterwards used to unsubscribe (ngOnDestroy).

Comment: What is your expected end result? Have you seen Rxjs's Zip?

Comment: The data that i just log in the example above is used to fill dropdown options and other things... What i expect is a proper solution for the scenario: httpCall1 -> parallel( httpCall2(using result of httpCall1), httpCall3) -> doing stuff with data from httpCalls 2 & 3.

Comment: If you wish to use the output of httpCall1 in httpCall2... you mean serial. Parallel means you want to execute all the requests at the same time... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested subscriptions are an anti patterns. You can refactor your code to return a single subscription with the use of `switchMap` operator.

```js
const sub = this.route.paramMap
  .pipe(switchMap(paramMap => {
    const id = paramMap.get('id');
    return forkJoin([
      this.componentService.getComponentDetails(id), 
      this.planService.getPlanTypes()
    ])
  })).subscribe(data => console.log(data))

this.subscriptions.add(sub)
```

Also, notice how I am using the paramMap instead of params. It is the preferred way of accessing the params in the newest versions of Angular.

Comment: Actually i tried something similar but got an error. I don't know why I got that error and whats the difference to your solution, but your solution works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy to help :)